# Why does the batchfile for loop only process the first value of a variable?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to find a specific folder on all drives. The list of drives are stored in the variable "drive_letter" and paths are stored in the variable "loc" delimited by an equal sign. The batchfile must check all combinations of drives and paths, however, the snippet below only checks for the first value on all listed drives and then exits.

```
@echo off
set drive_letter=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
set loc=T est=Te st=Tes t
FOR %%A in (%drive_letter%) do (
    FOR /f "delims==" %%a in ("%%A:%loc%") do ( 
        if exist "%%a" ( echo\ && echo Exists - "%%a" ) else ( echo Nonexistent - "%%a" )
    )
)
pause>nul
```

Expectation:

```
Nonexistent - "c:T est"
Nonexistent - "d:T est"
Nonexistent - "e:T est"
Nonexistent - "f:T est"
Nonexistent - "g:T est"
Nonexistent - "h:T est"
Nonexistent - "i:T est"
Nonexistent - "j:T est"
Nonexistent - "k:T est"
Nonexistent - "l:T est"
Nonexistent - "m:T est"
Nonexistent - "n:T est"
Nonexistent - "o:T est"
Nonexistent - "p:T est"
Nonexistent - "q:T est"
Nonexistent - "r:T est"
Nonexistent - "s:T est"
Nonexistent - "t:T est"
Nonexistent - "u:T est"
Nonexistent - "v:T est"
Nonexistent - "w:T est"
Nonexistent - "x:T est"
Nonexistent - "y:T est"
Nonexistent - "z:T est"

Nonexistent - "c:Te st"
Nonexistent - "d:Te st"
Nonexistent - "e:Te st"
Nonexistent - "f:Te st"
Nonexistent - "g:Te st"
Nonexistent - "h:Te st"
Nonexistent - "i:Te st"
Nonexistent - "j:Te st"
Nonexistent - "k:Te st"
Nonexistent - "l:Te st"
Nonexistent - "m:Te st"
Nonexistent - "n:Te st"
Nonexistent - "o:Te st"
Nonexistent - "p:Te st"
Nonexistent - "q:Te st"
Nonexistent - "r:Te st"
Nonexistent - "s:Te st"
Nonexistent - "t:Te st"
Nonexistent - "u:Te st"
Nonexistent - "v:Te st"
Nonexistent - "w:Te st"
Nonexistent - "x:Te st"
Nonexistent - "y:Te st"
Nonexistent - "z:Te st"

Nonexistent - "c:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "d:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "e:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "f:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "g:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "h:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "i:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "j:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "k:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "l:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "m:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "n:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "o:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "p:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "q:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "r:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "s:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "t:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "u:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "v:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "w:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "x:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "y:Tes t"
Nonexistent - "z:Tes t"
```

Actual result:

```
Nonexistent - "c:T est"
Nonexistent - "d:T est"
Nonexistent - "e:T est"
Nonexistent - "f:T est"
Nonexistent - "g:T est"
Nonexistent - "h:T est"
Nonexistent - "i:T est"
Nonexistent - "j:T est"
Nonexistent - "k:T est"
Nonexistent - "l:T est"
Nonexistent - "m:T est"
Nonexistent - "n:T est"
Nonexistent - "o:T est"
Nonexistent - "p:T est"
Nonexistent - "q:T est"
Nonexistent - "r:T est"
Nonexistent - "s:T est"
Nonexistent - "t:T est"
Nonexistent - "u:T est"
Nonexistent - "v:T est"
Nonexistent - "w:T est"
Nonexistent - "x:T est"
Nonexistent - "y:T est"
Nonexistent - "z:T est"
```

Comment: It's because a FOR /F only splits a value into tokens for the delimiter, it doesn't iterate over the parts. If you would have set `tokens=1-9` then you would see that `%%a` contains `c:T est` `%%b` and %%c  contains `T est`. Btw. To present a minimal example it's not necessary to show the complete alphabet, `c d e` would be enough

Comment: Gotcha. I tried "tokens=1-4 delims==" before posting as well as your suggestion "tokens=1-9 delims==" but still gave me the same result as only "delims==".

Comment: As said, that is the expected behavior, because FOR /F will not iterate over  a single line. You can't use FOR/F in this case or you have to modify your loc variable to be processed as multiple lines

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. I figured out how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you tell it to do.
The default for for/f is **tokens=1**
That is the reason you get only the first location processed.
But even if you correct this and process all three locations you won't get your expected output.
Your code requests: for alle drives give a result for all locations.
That is: first driveletter with first location
first driveletter with second location
first driveletter with third location
second driveletter with first location
etc.
Next is your code with changes to process all locations.

```
@echo off
set drive_letter=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
set loc=T est=Te st=Tes t
FOR %%A in (%drive_letter%) do (
    echo "%%A:%loc%"
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims==" %%a in ("%%A:%loc%") do ( 
        echo [%%A] [%%a] [%%b]  [%%c] 
        if exist "%%a" ( echo\ && echo Exists - "%%a" ) else ( echo Nonexistent - "%%a" )
        if exist "%%b" ( echo\ && echo Exists - "%%b" ) else ( echo Nonexistent - "%%b" )
        if exist "%%c" ( echo\ && echo Exists - "%%c" ) else ( echo Nonexistent - "%%c" )
    )
)
pause>nul
```

Your expected output suggest what you want is:
for all locations give a result for all drives.

Needed adaptations are:
Switch the 2 for commands.
Change the for/f into the for without /f
Both for's are essential the same. The for with location is only different because these are strings with spaces, so you have to encapsulate these strings in double quotes.
Add a backslash between drive and location so the script will search with full path.

Next the code you probably intended to create.

```
@echo off
set drive_letter=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
set loc="T est","Te st","Tes t"

FOR %%a in (%loc%) do ( 
    FOR %%A in (%drive_letter%) do (
        rem echo [%%A] [%%a] [%%~a]
        if exist "%%A:\%%~a" ( echo\ && echo Exists - "%%A:\%%~a" ) else ( echo Nonexistent - "%%A:\%%~a" )
    )
)

pause>nul
```